# How to use the yaml file of swagger to automatically update the interface between the front and back end?

Tags: vue.js, swagger

The jar package generated by swagger can be added to springboot. How to introduce the client code generated by swagger into Vue? If yaml file changes, how to update the front and back interfaces synchronously through the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do this and the steps are mentioned below:

1. Firstly you need to add swagger.yml file to SwaggerHub.
2. Now add a new integration for springboot backend code.
3. Sync with your GitHub and enable auto-sync.
4. Again add another integration for vue frontend code.
5. And again sync with your GitHub and enable auto-sync.
6. For vue frontend codebase, you need to integrate with [swagger-vue-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-vue-generator) to auto code generation.\
7. And for spring-boot server/backend code generation, you need to integrate spring-swagger-codegen-api-client code generator to spring project.
   Find the [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-rest-client-swagger-codegen) for integration with spring.

And overall spring code generator can be found at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codege.

> Now whenever you update any things in swagger yml it will automatically sync with that git repository and when you make the build of respective code than new/updated change will be sync automatically.